# Where is the user documentation for the `attach_library()` function?

Tags: 9

Where is the user documentation for `attach_library()`?

The function is described on this page, [Libraries can now be attached from Twig templates via an attach_library() function](https://www.drupal.org/node/2456753).

I'm trying to solve an issue where [`attach_library()` doesn't work for anonymous users but yet it works for authenticated users](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/312041/98721). I'm not getting any replies there, so hoping to get a pointer to where the docs are to understand how the function works.

Comment: The documentation for that function is here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/function/TwigExtension%3A%3AattachLibrary/9.4.x. I doubt it'll help, though, all the function does is render an attachment inside a render array. It doesn't make any decisions. By the sounds of it your problem is more likely related to cache

Comment: @Clive thanks for link! You're right it doesn't tell me much about my issue. I'd select your answer if it was an answer! No, my problem isn't cache-related, as flushing caches doesn't solve the issue of the library's <script> tag not being inserted into the DOM for anonymous users.

Comment: Have you checked that the template file where you added `attach_library()` is being used for anonymous users?

Answer (score -1):

That and various other ways are [documented on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-assets-css-js-to-a-drupal-theme-via-librariesyml#attach-library-specific-twig).

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but that page only explains at a high level how to add assets to a page. My need is more fundamental than that; ie: I already know how to add assets to a page - I'm trying to understand why Drupal doesn't honor the `attach_library()` function for anonymous users.

Comment: That’s already a question you have asked. I’ve answered this one.

Comment: Thanks @cilefen for the link, but that's not the documentation I'm looking for! I'm looking for the docs on a function related to Drupal Core. I need to know how `attach_library()` is being used underneath the template and theme layer.

Comment: @BrianZelip I just posted a link to it under the question, but you're right at the top of the rabbit hole there, that function just hooks into other APIs, it's those other APIs you'll need to dig down into.

Comment: In any case, above I've pointed rightly to the user documentation, which answers the question "Where is the user documentation for the `attach_library()` function?", which is this question.